# Global context menu listener or else How to register context menu for all views registered

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I need to find the way, how to dynamically register a context menu for all views registered. It could be easy, if there would be some global context menu listener. When the user clicked right button on some view, I'd have got some event with access to menu manager and then it would be swift.

I've been googling overall, but still haven't found any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can add the listener for one view you might be able to add it for all views by getting the list of all views:  `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getViewRegistry().getViews()`