# Toolbar items dynamically

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I need to create dynamically buttons in main toolbar. I found a solution, but I can create just one button (dynamic contribution item - class extending `ContributionItem`). But I need to create more than one button, but I cannot find the solution.

I'm fighting with task to create plugin, which parses a XML file containing structure of menu and toolbars. We've already done this plugin for Visual Studio. Its quite easy in principle, but I found swiftly, that not for Eclipse. There is one small but critical otherness. Plugins are implemented declaratively in Eclipse. The file `plugin.xml` is the gist of plugin's infrastructure, Java code is just ancillary.

The customer wants to refresh the menu and toolbar whenever the selected project is changed. Eclipse lacks several features needed to get the task done. Main menu and main toolbar are cteated at Eclipse's start-up and then they can be hardly rebuilt.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific. Eg. button to main toolbar or where? In Eclipse we usually use declarative contribution to any toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

In the most cases the conditions defined at enabledWhen/visibleWhen elements are sufficient to filter contributions according to the context (active part, selected object, whatever else).

If you need to have more freedom, please try E4 ToolControl that allows you to implement your own UI elements:

```java
    @PostConstruct
    public void createControls(Composite parent) {
        //your custom code here
    }
```

More details here https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#toolcontrols

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to have different buttons on the main toolbar depending on the selection of the project explorer (eg. 1 project is java project, the other is javascript etc.). First you will have to contribute to the main toolbar. I think there are some tutorial available so google will help. 
The main steps are:
1. create a command (org.eclipse.ui.commmands)
2. create a handler (org.eclipse.ui.handlers) with the previously declared command id
3. contribute to the main toolbar (org.eclipse.ui.menus) with menucontribution and commandId with the following locationURI: toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=misc

showing/hiding, enabling/disabling a menu item/button also can be done declaratively or "mixed". Declaratively means eg. using enabledWhen/visibleWhen...
Mixed means using property tester (org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTester). With this you can define your "enablement logic" in Java code.

Comment: I've been fighting last two months with Google. All tutorials supposed there was some constant set of commands declared in plugin descriptor. But I need to create it all dynamically and that seems to be an unsolvable problem. I cannot declare any item at all. I don't know commands in advance. Several things works. Popup menu works, but I cannot register dynamic popup menu for each view or editor. Main menu works, but it must have been build when Eclipse is finishing the startup. Further changes of menu's data model appear in view uncertainly. I'm not able to control the update of view.

Comment: (Note: To register popup menu for all views is one of my tasks. I've already posted these questions: [Global context menu listener or else How to register context menu for all views registered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988349/global-context-menu-listener-or-else-how-to-register-context-menu-for-all-views), [Dynamic popup menu for all views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087095/dynamic-popup-menu-for-all-views) and [Dynamic menu contribution with key bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028967/dynamic-menu-contribution-with-key-bindings/10100755))

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse e4 the UI is generated from a, EMF based, model. The Application.e4xmi serves as a base for that model. Contributions to the model can be done via fragments, which are again XML, or via processors. Processors are written in Java and use e4 services, like the part service, to modify the model at runtime.

I think you want to write a processor that parses your custom XML and modifies the eclipse e4 model accordingly.