# Dynamic popup menu for all views

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I need to provide a dynamic popup menu for all views. I can create a dynamic popup menu contributibution, but I must set the URI and register it for certain view. Now I'm trying to register the menu dynamically, when the user selects another view:

```
public class GlobalSelectionListener implements ISelectionListener {
    HashSet<IWorkbenchPart> extended = new HashSet<IWorkbenchPart>();

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
        if (!extended.contains(part)) {
            IWorkbenchPartSite wps = part.getSite();
            if (wps == null)
                return;
            //creates popup menu for this part
            MenuManager mgr = new MenuManager();
            mgr.add(new DynamicMenu()); //DynamicMenu extends ContributionItem
            wps.registerContextMenu("identifier." + mgr.hashCode(), mgr, wps.getSelectionProvider());
            extended.add(part);
            System.out.println(part + " menu extended");
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work. No one menu item appears in popup menu. I don't know, whether is it ever possible to do it this way. Is there any method to add popup menu for arbitrary view dynamically? It seems, that the `registerContextMenu()` method does something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not solved, nevertheless there is a workaround. It is possible to register the pop-up menu in `plugin.xml` file for all views and editors needed. Usualy the number of plugin usecases is limited. If you're writting a plugin, you know what you need the plugin for. Use the [Spy plug-in](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/spy/) (ALT+SHIFT+F1) to see the active menu contribution identifiers and register your contribution to the pop-up menu of all views and editors you need.